# Match 1 or more words separated by comma

Tags: replace, emeditor

I want to match in Emeditor any 1 or more word(s) or phrases (that follow a specific language name) separated by comma and ending in semicolon.

For example, I would like to match this string for Russian:

> Russian: радость сть, весе-веселье, весе' веселье, веселье;

And create wiki links in the replacement like this:

> Russian: [[радость сть]], [[весе-веселье]], [[весе' веселье]],
> [[веселье]];

This is the example text:

> Bulgarian: веселие, радост; Chinese Mandarin: 歡笑, 欢笑, 愉快, 高興, 高兴;
> Dutch: vrolijkheid; Finnish: ilo, hilpeys; French: gaieté; Georgian:
> მხიარულება, სიმხიარულე, სიხარული; German: Fröhlichkeit, Belustigung,
> Freude; Greek: ευθυμία, κέφι; Ancient Greek: εὐφροσύνη; Italian: gran
> gioia, allegria; Japanese: 笑い, 遊び, 喜び, 歓楽; Malayalam: ആഹ്ലാദം;
> Plautdietsch: Freid; Portuguese: alegria, júbilo; Russian: радость
> сть, весе-веселье, весе' веселье, веселье; Scottish Gaelic: sogan;
> Spanish: felicidad, alegría, júbilo; Swedish: munterhet, glädje

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do `(,|:) ([^,;]*)` => `$1 [[$2]]`

Comment: Essentially, all of your matching terms are either preceded by a comma (for the last term) or a colon (for the language name) and consist of any character except comma (to delimit the next term) or semicolon (to delimit the next language)

Comment: Here's a regex101 page showing that it works: https://regex101.com/r/DvC49k/1

Comment: Thanks, I want to only match the words following a specific language, ie Russian. The above regex matches translations for all languages.

Comment: What is the maximum number of terms that can follow a language name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just a couple of lines in the EmEditor macro should do it. 1st line identifies the language and selects that line, 2nd line makes the replacement. e.g. :

v3

```
document.selection.Find("(^|; )((Russian: )|(Ancient Greek: )|(Greek: )|(French: ))\\K[^;]*(?=$|;)",eeFindNext | eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeFindSelectAll,0);

document.selection.Replace("(\\b[^,;]+)(?=$|,)","[\\1]",eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceSelOnly | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp,eeExFindBOL | eeExFindEOL);
```

Comment: The result was:

`Russian: [[радость сть]], [[весе-веселье]], [[весе' веселье]], [[веселье]]; [[Scottish Gaelic: sogan]]; [[Spanish: felicidad]], [[alegría]], [[júbilo]]; [[Swedish: munterhet]], glädje`

Comment: Under Emeditor - Find / Find & Replace dialogue box  - Advanced button, Check and make sure the  if the "additional lines to search for Regular Expressions" is set to zero. Run the first line of code above only, to confirm it's only selecting the lines with Russian.

Comment: I've amended the first line code to hopefully only select a single line, irrespective of what you set for the additional lines.

Comment: Same result with new code + with unchecked "additional lines to search for Regular Expressions"

Comment: Tweaked the code above - try that.

Comment: Yes, that works. A couple of issues, I changed to `("(?<=; Russian: )` so that it will not match languages with same second part (I.e. "Ancient Greek" and "Greek"). How do I add extra languages in the first line? Tried `(?<=; Russian: |; Greek: )` but threw syntax errors

Comment: You can use multiple alternating positive lookbehinds like this: ((?<=; Russian: )|(?<=; Greek: )|(?<=; French: ))[^;]*;

I wouldn't recommend that, as the way you have amended, it will miss any instances where the language is right at the start. The v2 in the code above is probably a better way. If this works for youplease mark this as the answer.

Comment: Right, thanks, almost there, I tried `((Russian: )|(Ancient Greek: )|(Greek: )|(French: ))` but it failed for Ancient Greek.

Comment: Code updated to v3

Answer (score 0):

Find the Russian line and highlight it. Use 3 (non-regex) replacements with "selected text" option on:

| search | replace |
| --- | --- |
| `": "` | `": [["` |
| `", "` | `"]], [["` |
| `";"` | `"]];"` |

Comment: Thanks, I want to only match the words following a specific language, ie Russian. The above match translations for all languages.

Comment: @greektranslator does the edit help? Or does "Russian" appear many times in the file?

Comment: No, I want to be able to do this without any manual actions so as to use in a macro that will involve strings for more than one language.

Comment: What is the maximum number of terms that can follow a language?

Comment: Solving for an indefinite (IE no maximum) number of terms seems like the kind of thing that requires a context-free grammar. With a maximum number you could just make the additional terms optional and enumerate them in the regex.

Comment: Maximum is 10 terms.

Answer (score -1):

```
(?<Lang>Russian): (?<pre>(\[\[.*\]\],)*) (?<words>[^\[,;]+)(?<post>[^;]*?;)
```

Replace with

```
$Lang: $pre [[$words]]$post
```

Run repeatedly.

---

How's it work?
We anchor to text within the word "Russian" and the semicolon. Then we skip past already formatted values by matching them with a repeating capture group. (The anon group within `$pre`.) Once we find unformatted values (A string that isn't surrounded by `[[]],` ), we match until the comma/semicolon. Then we match everything after that up to the semicolon.

See it in action with [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RkZ4EP/1)

Comment: Thanks, I want to only match the words following a specific language in the sample text, ie Russian. The above regex matches translations for all languages.

Comment: Rebuilt for this condition.

Comment: Thanks, it does not seem to work on EmEditor (nor Notepad++ for that matter). The output I get after running it in the Russian string is `$Lang: $pre [[$words]]$post `

Comment: Also, it looks like in the regex example, in the "test string" dialogue there is text which is already in wikilinks ([[text]]). The original text has no wikilinks and is as quoted in my question. The substitution should result in wikilinks for the terms contained in the specific language.

Comment: Here is your regex with the original find text: https://regex101.com/r/cvbRqe/1

Comment: Sorry I know nothing about emeditor regex syntax. Confirm please if you interested in PCRE-specific solution.

Comment: Looks like emeditor uses backslash-delimited replacement strings rather than dollarsign-delimited. Should be an easy fix

Comment: Here is a possible PCRE-way https://regex101.com/r/2tggU7/1